# A Mutivariate Test

Tags: statistics

In a paper I applied a multivariate test but without describing any hypotheses to check. I described only research questions? Will paper likely be rejected?

Comment: This question should be fleshed out a little bit more. Even then, its really hard for any of us to know whether or not a paper will be rejected. Regardless, getting a paper rejected is a normal part of academia and I would not let it bother you.

Comment: @JWH2006 - well, it should bother you enough to do a better job on the next one, but yes, it should not be something to lose sleep about.

Answer (score 2):

It is impossible to say how the reviewers will judge it, but it sounds like it has high likelihood of rejection. However, you should be able to improve the paper by making it more complete and submitting it again, perhaps to the same place.

If you are a student, you should get advice on these things from experienced faculty members or advisors.